# Retrieving user's permissions for a given database ref rather than the data itself?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm building an app in javascript using react + redux that talks to firebase. Different users with different permissions (based on user roles) will use this app, and so I'd like to render different components depending on the user's permissions.

Now, since I already have all the permissions as rules in firebase, I don't want to duplicate that data in the client as well. I'd rather ask firebase what the current logged in user can and cannot do.

This seems impossible to do in firebase. What I'd like to be able to do is something like this:

```
var canReadBars = firebase.database().ref('foo/bar').hasPermission('read');
if (canReadBars){
  // render the component
}
```

A (rather ugly) workaround is to simply fetch the data itself and determining what to render based on whether I get PERMISSION_DENIED or not, but that doesn't really work for writes.

I've googled this for hours trying to find an answer. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase intentionally exposes a generic error message to the client when the user doesn't have access permission to the data.

There is no way for a client to get a list of the permissions it has in the database. Nor is there a way to expose user-friendly error messages.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But I'm not really looking for any of those things. I just need firebase to tell me whether or not I can write/read to a particular path. I don't need a list of permissions or some kind of error message, a simple true or false would suffice.

Comment: There is no API for that.

Comment: Ok, but are there any plans to implement a feature like that? If not, are there any other workarounds? I imagine that would be very useful for other developers as well.

Comment: If you're still looking for a workaround (or for anyone else stumbling on this), one way to do it is to store user roles on the firebase database under a users node. Each user document is stored under their uid, and specify in rules that these can only be read by an authorized user with matching uid.